# Get the size to a snapshot via Powershell in Hyper-V

Tags: powershell, snapshot, hyper-v

Good Evening, I am developing a C# too, that is supposed to help users to control VMs on a server.
Now I have created the functions to create and erase Snapshots of these VMs and want to create a function to list all Snapshots of a VM including a view selected Snapshot parameter. With:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock { Get-VMSnapshot -VMName VMName |Select-Object}`

I am able to get nearly all information that are requested but the total size of the Snapshot itself.

However I could get the size with this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock {Get-VM -VMName VMName | gci -r -Filter *.avhd*| select @{Name="MB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Mb}}, *}
```

Not to get the two results together I compared the creation time of these two with a tolerance of up to 10 seconds and took the closest one. (Primitive I know), but now it becomes even more complicated.

If I now use a Snapshot to set the VM to this state, the time of the File creation changes and so my previous method stops working completely.

Why I want to know is, is there a better way to compare these two results or even better, to get the Snapshot size without such primitive comparisons?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below one-liners should suffice your need.

1)

```
Get-VM | Sort Name | Get-Snapshot | Where { $_.Name.Length -gt 0 } | Select VM,Name,Created,SizeMB
```

2)

```
Get-VM | Format-Table Name, @{Label="NumSnapshots";Expression={(Get-Snapshot -VM $_ | Measure-Object).Count}}, @{Label="TotalSnapShotSizeMB";Expression={(Get-Snapshot -VM $_ | Measure-Object -Sum SizeMB).Sum}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first one doesn't work because the Information set of the Snapshot doesn't contain its own size, somehow the creator of Hyper-V seemed to be not aware that size is an important value if you have to work with any kind of files.
The second sadly returns only the VM Name, the columns for `NumSnapshots` and `TotalSnapShotSizeMB` stay empty, also size for one screenshot would be what I need, the total size of all snapshots sadly doesn't help me that much.
But I will definitely try to play a little with Measure-Object, this seems like a potential solution to my problem.

Comment: @Etaila : Just tweak a little on the second code then and you will be able to pick . I do not have the infra to pick right now. I need time then to build one. Hope it helps then

Comment: @Etaila : Accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: till now it helped but didn't solve my problem, so I am waiting a little if someone else gets an idea for a solution.

Comment: Could you post what you are trying . May be I can look into it,